# Ubuntu 14.04, Chromium and Pepperflash

Tags: 14.04, flash, chromium

How could I have always Flash in Chromium (Pepperflash) up-to-date in Ubuntu 14.04?
Right now I have Flash **20.0.0.306** in Chromium **51.0.2704.79** Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit). 
Theoretically, according to *adobe.com/it/software/flash/about/* Flash **22.0.0.192** should be available.

The package pepperflashplugin-nonfree is not installed, but pepflashplugin-installer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I've found out why.
I removed accidentally the repository

*deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/skunk/pepper-flash/ubuntu trusty main*

Now it is up-to-date.